# can I execute an aspx file in a class library and get the result as a string?

Tags: c#, code-generation, asp.net

I have an c# Class Library where I need some dynamic template based text.
Instead of inventing my own template parser I thought I could create an aspx file in my project that is executed at runtime and, instead of viewing the output in a browser, I want a StreamReader or string object that holds the result.

Is that possible? And if yes, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to struggle more than is necessary with this approach.  You'd need an ASP.NET host like IIS.

Personally, I'd recommend an existing template processor.  I've heard (on a Hanselminutes or DotNetRocks podcast, I think) that you might even be able to host the T4 system in your application.  I'll have a look and see if I've remembered that correctly.

### Update

Here's a link on [hosting T4 templating in your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126519.aspx).

Comment: Meanwhile I created my own little Template Engine that uses some Regex magic and Reflection to produce the desired output. But the Link could be interesting in the near future. thx.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net is designed to be run in a web server engine - you would also have to deploy this to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Calling ASPX Pages from a Library would be possible (see Cassini WebServer) but I would recommend another tool:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/T4BasedCodeGenerator.aspx

We use it in our Project - slightly adapted for our needs